# Angular (space) keyevent is behaving like a (tab) after input field disabled

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have come across some rather bizarre behaviour with an input of mine.

I want to do some stuff everytime a user hits the **enter** or **space** key in my input field. When they hit one of these keys, I disable the field until I have finished doing some stuff.

When I hit the **enter* key (*keyCode = 32*) everything works as planned - the field is disabled until the function does it's stuff.

However, which I hit the **space** key (*keyCode = 13*) once the field gets disabled the focus jumps to the next element instead of staying where it should!

The typescript looks like this:

```
podcastsKeyDown(event) {
    if(event.keyCode == 32 || event.keyCode == 13) {
        this.disableInput = true;
    }
}
```

The html looks like this:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="text"  
    [disabled]="disableInput" (keydown)="keyDown($event)">
```

If I remove the following line:

```
this.disableInput = true;
```

the behaviour is as expected. How bizarre!

Is there anyway to prevent the focus from shifting like this? It is extremely odd behaviour.

Thanks in advance,

Tom

Comment: It is working as expected, how a disabled control can have focus ?

Comment: @SunilSingh It is not working as expected - it is shifting focus to next element for a (space) but not for an (enter)

Comment: Please create the stackblitz demo for this.

Answer (score 0):

Add the "tabindex" attribute to all proceeding elements you don't want users tabbing to. This works with shift-tab too:

```
<input tabindex="-1">
```

Handy because it prevents tabbing, but still allows the user to select the following field via mouse.

Otherwise, I think a `(focus)="someFocusEvent($event)"` could be used to disable the focused element. Add some intelligence from there to determine whether or not the field should be disabled, or whatever you need to do upon focus.